# How to play alarm sound continuously in background

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I am developing an application where I want to play an alarm. The alarm should start ringing in background as soon as I receive local notification and should stop when I press button.

Here is my code

```
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.timePicker date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
    fromDate:pickerDate];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
    fromDate:pickerDate];

NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
NSLog(@"set hour component %ld",(long)[timeComponents hour]); // Notification will fire in one minute

[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
NSLog(@"set setMinute component %ld",(long)[timeComponents minute]);
[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; //Create the localNotification object
[localNotification setFireDate:itemDate]; 
//Set the date when the alert will be launched using the date adding the time the user selected on the timer

[localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open"]; //The button's text that launches the application and is shown in the alert
[localNotification setAlertBody:@"Wake up"]; //Set the message in the notification from the textField's text
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[localNotification setHasAction: YES]; //Set that pushing the button will launch the application
[localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1];
//Set the Application Icon Badge Number of the application's icon to the current Application Icon Badge Number plus 1
[localNotification setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Alarm1" forKey:@"uid"]];
if (isRepeat) {
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
//Schedule the notification with the system
```

Using the above code the sound plays only for 30sec. I want it to play continuously. I searched a lot but could not find.

Thanks

Comment: use time interval concept

Comment: hi you can use the AVAudioPlayer for this it will work in backgound .

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that like the audio should automatically start playing as soon as notification is received

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can not be done , by saying this i mean you cannot play sound in background when app is in background like you are saying on receiving notification . Apple push and local both notification does not support this , you can only add tink sound for notification but it will not going to playing continuously .

If you want to play sound in background it can only be done if the sound started playing in foreground than you went in background than it will only keep playing in background using AVAudioPlayer Session PlayBack.

And you if you think you can add timer but timer also do not work in background.